# SQL search contains first string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have table with `varchar` column as below:

```
    +---------+-----------+
    | FruitId | FruitName |
    +---------+-----------+
    |     123 | Apple     |
    |     123 | Mango     |
    |     145 | Mango     |
    +---------+-----------+
```

**Query**

```
select * from Fruits with (nolock) where FruitId  like '123 something something%'
```

**Expected Results:**

```
123     Apple
123     Mango
```

**Query**

```
select * from Fruits with (nolock) where FruitName  like 'Apple something something%'
```

**Expected Results:**

```
123     Apple
```

But the above query's doesnt works , why ?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

```
select * from Fruits with (nolock) where FruitId  like '123 something something%' 
             or FruitName like 'Apple something something%'
```

Even this doesn't work, hope we have to concatenate both columns.

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`

Comment: Your are querying two separate fields.

Comment: When you write `FruitID LIKE '123 Apple%'` you're asking for all rows where the `FruitID` column starts with `123 Apple`.  But you don't have any such columns.  You ***appear*** to want `WHERE FruitID = 123 AND FruitName = 'Apple'` *(all rows where the FruitID is equal to 123 and where the FruitName is also equal to Apple)*, but as you haven't said what you actually want, it's impossible to be certain...

Comment: @PeterSmith , yes i know that , but user can search for `FruitId` like 123 with some other text

Comment: What does `WITH (NOLOCK)` do?

Comment: @stom Then you should be ***explicitly*** clear as to what a user is able to enter, what such values would *mean*, and then describe *(using examples)* the logic you'd like to implement.

Comment: @SalmanA : It allows the query to run against a table that's locked by other processes.  Such as one that's being written to by another transaction.  It's something the OP shouldn't be doing, it's incredibly dangerous if you give a damn about data quality, but that's a side note to the question being asked.

Comment: @PeterSmith Columns not a fields

Comment: @MatBailie I know. I am actually wondering if OP knows that or did he just copy-paste this from somewhere because it looks cool.

Comment: @SalmanA why you have deleted the answer ? Isn't it efficient ?

Comment: It did not match the results you were expecting (`123 Apple` will not match `123 Mango`).

Comment: @SalmanA , Sorry actually I think you didn't understand my question, `123 Apple` should Match `123` and `Apple 123` should match `Apple`, hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52055739/2218697) answer will solve my problem, but don't know if `CONCAT` has any performance issue ?

Comment: Your implementation is completely wrong. I would suggest you to change the approach. Because end user is not going to write query is SQL Server. He will pass something in text box. In the middle layer/language (C#, Php etc) you can split the string. Numeric value will be FruitId and Other string will be FruitName. According to the string you can generate dynamic sql query with multiple filters. Usually ID column's are unique.

Comment: User is typing in textbox not in Management studio. You just need to split the User's input. Then Create query in code (php/C#/Java).

Comment: @DeepakKumar End user types in text box , `123 something something` should match `123` and `Apple something something` should match `Apple` that's my requirement.

Comment: Then you can split his input in or not ? If you can split you can apply this business logic and well.

Comment: @DeepakKumar , no I don't want split because `FruitId` can have some characters too , I want to run `LIKE` against tow columns and return the results. I will get my answer soon. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179004/discussion-between-deepak-kumar-and-stom).

Comment: That's wrong thing. Performance will be poor. User can do sql injection as well. You can't use indexes in that.

Comment: @DeepakKumar , I have another `Id` to do indexes, thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @stom... My answer has been updated. which contains query without `+` and `CONCAT`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way by concatenating both column

```
select * from Fruits with (nolock) where CONCAT(FruitId , ' ', FruitName ) 
         like '123 Apple%' OR CONCAT(FruitName , ' ', FruitId) like 'Apple 123%'
```

Comment: Thanks, `123 something something` should match `123` and `Apple something something` should match `Apple` .I have updated the query in question Kindly check.

Comment: No, for that you have to do like "123%" or "Apple%"

Comment: How you can say that? Query nature is depends on the requirement.

Comment: @JERRY,How you match `123 something something`  with `123`

Comment: For that you need to `CONCAT` columns

Comment: @JERRY, Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If i understood your problem correctly, you should be using OR in your where clause like below

Query#1

```
select * from Fruits with (nolock) where FruitId  like '123 Apple%'
```

should be

```
select * from Fruits with (nolock) where FruitId  like '123' OR FruitName like 'Apple'
```

Query #2

```
select * from Fruits with (nolock) where FruitName  like 'Apple 123%'
```

should be framed like

```
select * from Fruits with (nolock) where FruitName  like 'Apple' OR FruitId like  '123'
```

Comment: Thanks, `123 something something` should match `123` and `Apple something something` should match `Apple` .I have updated the query in question Kindly check. Why you are not using `CONCAT` does it has performance issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

User Input: `123 something-something...`

**Query 1**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   fruits WITH (nolock) 
WHERE  '123 something-something...' LIKE Concat(fruitid, '%')
```

**Result**

```
+---------+-----------+
| FruitId | FruitName |
+---------+-----------+
|     123 | Apple     |
|     123 | Mango     |
+---------+-----------+
```

User Input: `Apple something-something...`

**Query 2**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   fruits WITH (nolock) 
WHERE  'Apple something-something...' LIKE Concat(fruitname, '%')
```

**Result**

```
+---------+-----------+
| FruitId | FruitName |
+---------+-----------+
|     123 | Apple     |
+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: You can use `+` instead of `CONCAT`. However, `CONCAT` is the recommended way. According to [this article](http://www.dbafire.com/2015/07/09/what-is-the-difference-between-and-concat-function-in-sql/), there is no major performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    FruitId VARCHAR(50), 
    FruitName VARCHAR(50)
)
DECLARE @Src VARCHAR(50)='Apple 123'

INSERT INTO @T 
VALUES(123, 'Apple'),
(123, 'Mango'),
(145, 'Mango');

SELECT
    *
    FROM @T
        WHERE FruitId like LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Src,1,CHARINDEX(' ',@Src))))+'%'
            OR
            FruitName like LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Src,1,CHARINDEX(' ',@Src))))+'%'
```

Comment: I have updated question with more info, kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate values to compare both with `LIKE` at once:

```
CREATE TABLE fruits(FruitId VARCHAR(256), FruitName VARCHAR(256));
INSERT INTO fruits VALUES(123, 'Apple'),(123, 'Mango'),(145, 'Mango');

SELECT FruitId, FruitName 
FROM fruits 
WHERE FruitId+' '+FruitName like '123 Apple%' OR FruitName+' '+FruitId like '123 Apple%'
```

Comment: No you can use **CONCAT** or **"+"** to Concatenate multiple columns. But make sure your `SELECT` Query should be defined with `READ UNCOMMITTED` or `WITH(NOLOCK)`.

Comment: Let me know the use of `OR FruitName+' '+FruitId like '123 Apple%'`